# Swagger-codegen is creates a model where parameters have been overwritten by a reference to another model

Tags: swift, swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen

I'm using swagger-codegen to generate a swift client. My swagger.yaml file contains the following model definitions:

```
RelationshipCollection:
    type: object
    description: a collection of relationships
    required:
      - pagination
      - relationships
    properties:
      pagination:
        $ref: '#/definitions/PaginationData'
      relationships:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: '#/definitions/Relationship'
  Relationship:
    type: object
    description: Indicates the relationship between a parent and a student.
    properties:
      relationship_id:
        type: integer
        format: int32
      parent:
        $ref: '#/definitions/SwaggerUser'
      student:
        $ref: '#/definitions/SwaggerUser'
  RelationshipCreate:
    name: RelationshipCreate
    type: object
    description: What a student must send to the system to form a `Relationship` with their parent. Cannot be created without an `Invitation`.
    required:
      - token
      - security_answer
    properties:
      token:
        type: string
        example: jRMcN645BQyDr67yHR3qjsJF
        description: The token from the `Invitation` used to create this relationship
      security_answer:
        type: string
        example: Some kind of answer to a security question
        description: The answer to the security question asked in the `Invitation`
```

When I generate the code using swagger-codegen I get the following model for Relationship.

```
open class Relationship: Codable {

    public var relationshipCreate: RelationshipCreate



    public init(relationshipCreate: RelationshipCreate) {
        self.relationshipCreate = relationshipCreate
    }


    // Encodable protocol methods

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {

        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: String.self)

        try container.encode(relationshipCreate, forKey: "relationshipCreate")
    }

    // Decodable protocol methods

    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: String.self)

        relationshipCreate = try container.decode(RelationshipCreate.self, forKey: "relationshipCreate")
    }
}
```

I am expecting the following:

```
open class Relationship: Codable {

    public var relationshipId: Int?
    public var parent: SwaggerUser?
    public var student: SwaggerUser?


    public init(relationshipID: Int?, parent: SwaggerUser?, student: SwaggerUser?) {
        self.relationshipID = relationshipID
        self.parent = parent
        self.student = student
    }
...

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've stumbled over the solution to this. In our API we have a post request that returns the following.

```
{
  "relationship": {
    "token": "jRMcN645BQyDr67yHR3qjsJF",
    "security_answer": "Some kind of answer to a security question"
  }
}
```

Here is the associated swagger code:

```
post:
  summary: Create a relationship
  description: Create a relationship between a parent and a student. The student accepts the parent's `Invitation` by providing it's `token` and the correct answer to their `security_question`. Also marks the invitation as accepted so it cannot be used again.
  tags:
    - Relationships
  parameters:
    - $ref: '#/parameters/user_id'
    - name: Accept-Language
      description: 'see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language'
      in: header
      type: string
      default: en
    - in: body
      name: relationship
      schema:
        type: object
        required:
          - relationship
        properties:
          relationship:
            $ref: '#/definitions/RelationshipCreate'
  responses:
    '201':
      description: ''
      schema:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Relationship'
    '400':
      description: Bad Request
```

The value for the key "relationship" is a RelationshipCreation object. Swagger-codegen appears to parse this response object and over-writing the intended Relationship model with a model with this key as its name and a property of type RelationshipCreation.

The takeaway, be careful when using keys that match your existing models, you may overwrite your existing models when the code is generated.